# Oracle function that returns a bool value if succedeed or failed

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm developing an app using Oracle 11g and ODP.NET, C# and I'm a beginner in Oracle stored procedures.
What I need is to write a stored function that will delete a record from a table.

Let's say function fu_delete_user(p_user_id) that deletes the user with that id from table Users. But, maybe due to a constraint, the delete statement threw an exception. In this case I want the function to return false, else it should return true.

How should I write this function / call it from c# ?
Thank you!

Comment: what do you have so far?  have you written your oracle function?  do you have a db connection?

Comment: There's no reason why a Oracle **function** can't return a boolean. Will C# be able to recognise this? If all you're deleting is a record then you don't need a procedure at all.

Comment: @c0deNinja yes, I have the connection, I would just need a sample of how to write the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea of the code, it would be better in your case to use a function as they are designed to always return a value.
Procedures can return values through `OUT` parameters (as in the example I have given).

Using a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION p_delete_user (
   p_user_id IN NUMBER
)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM users
     WHERE user_id = p_user_id;
   --
   RETURN true;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Log error
      RETURN false;
END p_delete_user;
```

Using a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE p_delete_user (
   p_user_id IN NUMBER,
   p_success OUT BOOLEAN
)
IS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM users
     WHERE user_id = p_user_id;
   --
   p_success := true;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN others
   THEN
      -- Log error
      p_success := false;
END p_delete_user;
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

Unless you can guarantee this will be used only within pl/sql, then you may want to make return value a number (1=true, 0=false).  SQL doesn't understand boolean (besides, my old school brain thinks in terms of 1s and 0s ;)